# Wicket: Mapping a type safe page constructor to a readable URL

Tags: java, url, wicket

I use Wicket 6.1 and I am trying to figure out how to make my page flows have nicer, more bookmarkable URL's.

I use type safe constructors a lot, so my code will typically look like this:

```
class SearchResultsPage extends WebPage {
  public SearchResultsPage(SearchResultsModel model) {
     // display the data in the model
  }
}
```

To navigate to the page I have code like this:

```
AjaxButton ajaxButton = new IndicatingAjaxButton("ajaxbutton") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        SearchResultsModel results = search(kriteriamodel)                
        getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(new SearchResultsPage(results));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        target.add(feedback);
    }
};
```

Now when I reach the result page, my URL will look something like searchresults?5

I would like to be able to encode the search-parameters into a URL that the user could bookmark for later referal.

I am aware that I can use the PageParameters map and manually map my objects to and from that structure. But I am looking for a more *elegant* solution.

- I am looking for pointers to some clever interface, that my page or
  model should implement, to make the page more bookmarkable.
- An example would be nice too.
- Ideally only code in the Page/Model should be changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is something like this:

```
class SearchResultsPage extends WebPage {

  public static PageParameters convertModelToParam(SearchResultsModel model) {
     ...
  }

  public static SearchResultModel convertParamToModel( PageParameters param ) {
    //this is for convenience only
    ...
  }

  public SearchResultsPage( PageParameters param ) {
    this( convertParamToModel( param ) );
  }

  private SearchResultsPage(SearchResultsModel model) {
    // display the data in the model
  }
}
```

This way your page becomes bookmarkable but you get to keep your type-safe constructors. The obvious flaw here is that once you have a constructor that accepts `PageParameters`, there's no way to make sure that it came from the appropriate conversion method. But when you think about it, it's an accurate model of the real world: users are free to edit the query string in your URL too and your application should be able to handle it.

Remember, once a page can be bookmarked, parameters become user input and therefore they absolutely must be sanitised before you convert them into your business objects. No automated system will do that for you.

Comment: Yours is a pragmatic solution. I grant you that.  
  
I am not looking for an automated solution. I am aware that at some point I have to map my objects to pageparameters.  

But I was hoping for an _elegant_ solution. Some clever way to mount the page and/or some interface that my page could implement. I really despise static methods and with your solution I also have to remember to call the static method instad of the nice type safe one.

Comment: It wasn't what I was looking for, but I am going to accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Of course there are many variations to this theme. I added static methods to demonstrate the concept, but depending on your architecture you can have a separate factory that does all the conversions, or you can do the conversion in an instance method/constructor of the model object itself.